# How to copy the whole path of a file in VS Code while using WSL and WSL extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Some time ago, I had WSL 2, and used VS Code. When I copied the path of a file, it copied like this:

```
file://wsl%24/Ubuntu-20.04/home/fernando/javascript_local/index.html
```

After installing WSL extension and an update of VS Code, when I copy the path, it looks like this:

```
/home/fernando/repos/odin-recipes/index.html"
```

I want to copy it including "file://wsl%24/Ubuntu-20.04/".

I have already:

1. Enabled "Editor: Copy With Syntax Highlighting" in: user, remote [WSL: Ubuntu-20.04], workspace
2. Disabled extensions
3. Reset VS Code to default settings

Current versions of:
VS Code: 1.78.2
WSL: Version 2, Ubuntu-20.04
WSL extension: v0.78.8

Also, before installing the WSL extension for VS Code, I could write "code ." in the WSL console and it would take me to my folders. Now when I do that while the extension is disabled, I can't access my folders using "code ." (it shows an error), I can only access while WSL extension is enabled.

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/63633

Comment: 1. Added version numbers
2. Installed older versions of WSL extension, the problem continues. I guess then, the problem is VS code configuration.
I tried writing in the json file "remote.WSL.copyPath.withLinuxPrefix": true
But didn't solve the problem.
What else can I do?

Comment: Extensions provided in the solutions inside the link don't work too

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!!!!
Apparently, all I had to do:
Inside VS code, click on the blue button on the border left down on the screen. Change from "WSL" to open in windows.
Once the file created inside WSL is open with the option "open in windows", when I paste the file direction in the web browser, it is pasted with the file://wsl%24/Ubuntu-20.04 direction